# How to upload an image after a screenshot in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinyxml

How to upload an image in a past from my project after a screenshot and pasted in TinyMCE? Because my database not save images, so I must to save the url way . In the TinyMCE I want to know how make a preprocess these image and save this image in a past from my project and in the editor stay the url way  and after that to send the form to database.

Please, someone can help me with an example in javascript?

I tried with multer in backend to get this variable with texts and images arrived from form, but is not possible, because the multer not filter images and texts and after separete, this variable must to come separete just with images or files.